# How do I assign data obtained using BeatifulSoup4 to a variable as a float or integer?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am new to Python, sorry for such a noob question but I have two problems with the following code:

1) I'm trying to scrape data from a website and I'm having problems getting the data through anything other than the `for` loop and therefore I need to continue the loop with `print` in order to be able to assign the value to a variable in the following command:

```
receivables2017 = receivables2017.string
```

2) Next I'm trying to assign the specific values (for example `Receivables2017`) to the `aapl` dictionary but I am unable to get the value in the dictionary in the form of a `float` or `int` which is needed to later be applied to equations.

Help will be much appreciated, thank you!

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

#Cash & Cash Equivalents
for cash_and_equivalents2017 in soup.find_all('td')[33]:
    print(cash_and_equivalents2017.string)

cash_and_equivalents2017 = cash_and_equivalents2017.string

for cash_and_equivalents2016 in soup.find_all('td')[34]:
print(cash_and_equivalents2016.string)

cash_and_equivalents2016 = cash_and_equivalents2016.string

#Receivables
for receivables2017 in soup.find_all('td')[39]:
    print(receivables2017.string)

receivables2017 = receivables2017.string

for receivables2016 in soup.find_all('td')[40]:
    print(receivables2016.string)

receivables2016 = receivables2016.string



aapl = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
            {'2017': cash_and_equivalents2017,
             '2016': cash_and_equivalents2016},
        'Receivables':
            {'2017': receivables2017,
             '2016': receivables2016}
        {

print(aapl)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `for` loop to assign the values to variables:

```
for receivables2016 in soup.find_all('td')[40]:
    print(receivables2016.string)
```

Can be shortened to:

```
receivables2016 = soup.find_all('td')[40].string
```

If you try to iterate over the soup's element, it indeed yields one object even if it contains just one element. That's how it was designed to work. But it's actually an element containing some data and not necessarily an iterable (list, tuple etc).
You should take a look at python's iterators and generators:
https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#the-iteration-protocol

If you don't want a block of code to do anything, just use `pass`

```
for i in range(10):
    pass # will iterate 10 times but won't don anything
```

Or if you defined a function but haven't decided on the implementation yet:

```
def my_funct():
    pass
```

If `my_funct` is called it will return by default `None` since no return value is declared.

I see that the values you want to have in your dict have the decimal point as `,`. If it's a string you could easily just replace the comma with a dot and convert it to a float afterwards:

```
aapl = {'Cash & Cash Equivalents':
            {'2017': float(cash_and_equivalents2017.replace(",", ".")),
             '2016': float(cash_and_equivalents2016.replace(",", "."))},
        'Receivables':
            {'2017': float(receivables2017.replace(",", ".")),
             '2016': float(receivables2016.replace(",", "."))}
        }
```

Using python's built-in `int()` function you can turn numerical strings into integers. Keep in mind that they have to be valid integers even if string format. This won't work and will throw an `ValueError`:

```
int(receivables2016.replace(",", "."))
```

In this case you'll have to convert the string to float and to an integer afterwards:

```
int(float(receivables2016.replace(",", ".")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but:

```
aapl = dict([('Cash & Cash Equivalents 2017', cash_and_equivalents2017),
         ('Cash & Cash Equivalents 2016', cash_and_equivalents2016),
         ('Receivables 2017', receivables2017),
         ('Receivables 2016', receivables2016)])

print(aapl)
```

Worked for me to return:

```
{'Cash & Cash Equivalents 2016': '67,155', 'Receivables 2016': '29,299', 'Cash & Cash Equivalents 2017': '74,181', 'Receivables 2017': '35,673'}
```